# Detect session hang and kill it

Tags: asp.net, .net, algorithm, debugging, iis

I have an asp.net page that runs certain algorithm and returns it's output. I was wondering what will happen and how to handle a case where the algorithm due to a bug goes into infinite loop. It will hog the cpu and other sessions will be served very slowly.

I would love to have a way to tell IIS, if processing Algo.aspx takes more than 5 seconds, kill it or something like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in IIS. What you can do instead is to perform the work in a background thread and measure the time it takes to complete this background task and simply kill the thread if the wait time is longer than expected.

You may take a look at the [WaitHandle.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477(v=VS.100).aspx) method which allows you to specify a timeout for waiting for a particular event to be signaled from a background thread for example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [ScriptTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout.aspx) property. It will abort the page if the time is exceeded. It only works when the debugging property is set to true, though.